# How can I use Google Material Icons in css pseudo:before in content with Wordpress and OxygenBuilder

Tags: css

Hello I am trying to get Material Icons to work. I have installed Headers and footers plugin to load this Stylesheet in the header:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then add this CSS

```
li.bulletpoint {
    font-family: 'Material Design Icons';
    content: "\f054";
}
```

But this doesnt work, any suggestions?

Comment: They should have documentation on how to use it on their website.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, still the same with the stylesheet to put it in the header.

This is the code for CSS

```
.li--package {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.li--package li:before {
font-family: "Material Icons";
    content: '\e5cc';
```